# Foreign key auto insert values

Tags: php, mysql

How to auto insert values from `TBL_PACKAGE` into foreign key on `TBL_MEMBER`?

**Example :** If I have two tables like :

**TBL_MEMBER**

```
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | USER_NAME | PACKAGE_ID_FK | UPDATE_TIMES_FK |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|            No data available in table            |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**TBL_PACKAGE**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| ID | PACKAGE_NAME | UPDATE_TIMES |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | FREE         |            5 |
|  2 | PREMIUM      |           10 |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

When `USER1` has been registered `USER1` will be gets `FREE` package Then `PACKAGE_ID_FK` will auto insert value into `1` and `UPDATE_TIMES_FK` auto insert value into `5`.

**TBL_MEMBER** should look like this :

```
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | USER_NAME | PACKAGE_ID_FK | UPDATE_TIMES_FK |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | USER1     |             1 |               5 |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

And when registered user buy a `PREMIUM` package that will auto set `PACKAGE_ID_FK` value into `2` and `UPDATE_TIMES_FK` value into `10`.

**TBL_MEMBER** should look like this after `USER1` buy a `PREMIUM` package :

```
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | USER_NAME | PACKAGE_ID_FK | UPDATE_TIMES_FK |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | USER1     |             2 |              10 |
+----+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: how are you creating a relation between member and package before inserting the data

Comment: foreign keys don't insert anything, you would use a TRIGGER.

Comment: What you describe is application logic and it is a programmer's task to implement it. No database can guess what your application would like to do an automatically update your tables! When a user registers, your application inserts a record into the members table with package id set to 1. When the users buys a package, then your applucation updates the given record.

Comment: @Shadow Then I  need to set all of those values on `INSTER INTO` code in PHP?

Comment: That's correct. And in update statements as well.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you, Can I ask you one more question? If I have many users with different package in my `TBL_MEMBER` And How do I set MySQL event to auto reset `UPDATE_TIMES` into default value of users package?

Comment: The answer is that you should probably not have an auto updates field in the members table, since it is already in the packages table and you can get its value via a join. I think you should read a book on the basics of database design.

Comment: @Shadow Like `UPDATE ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... SET ...` right?